# Star Trek novel with Kirk stepping on a venomous creature?

Tags: story-identification, star-trek, episode-identification, star-trek-eu

In which Star Trek novel did Kirk step on a venomous creature? The creature may be known as a "Judas Boot"?

Comment: Are you sure he only stepped on it and he didn't kiss it or something??

Answer (score 5):

The novel is [Double, Double](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Double,_Double) by Michael Jan Friedman.

> On a routine exploratory mission, the Starship USS Hood picks up a
> distress signal from a research expedition thought lost long ago – the
> expedition of Dr. Roger Korby, one of the centuries' greatest
> scientific minds. Korby himself is dead, it seems, but his colleagues
> have made a most incredible discovery – a discovery they insist the
> Hood's captain see for himself. Reluctantly, the captain agrees to
> beam down…

The creature is called a '*Malachi's Boot*' not a Judas Boot.

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. You could improve this answer by editing it to provide a bit more info on the book, and specifying the ways in which it matches the one described in the question.

Comment: The boot creature doesn't have a wiki entry but fyi on the novel https://memory-beta.fandom.com/wiki/Double,_Double

Answer (score 2):

I don't know about stepping on a venomous creature, but in the novel First Frontier (book 75) Cpt. Kirk has been stung by a "hairy thrill killer scorpion (I believe it was called)." There was no cure but, Dr. McCoy can keep treating the symptoms until the poison finally wears off.

Comment: No, but thank you for the response.

Comment: I think the setting was a diplomatic conference, and Kirk needed to walk to the conference secretly, for some reason.

Comment: Drat and I've read nearly all of them.  Just can't seem to place that one.